# saint Louis fed quarterly review style

Tags: titles, boxes

How can I generate a title that is similar in appearance to the titles in the *St. Louis FED review Journal*. [I've linked the latest paper from that journal](http://research.stlouisfed.org/publications/review/article/10381).

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a rather simple solution with mdframed.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 

\begin{document}

\begin{addmargin}[-2.1cm]{0pt}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!10,linecolor=none]
\flushright
\textsf{\LARGE Monetary Policy Normalization in the United States}
\vskip36pt
\textit{Stephen Williamson} 
\end{mdframed}  

\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also a solution with tikz:

```
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{%  
\leftskip-2cm
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle,fill=blue!15,inner xsep=12pt, inner ysep=6pt, outer ysep=10pt]{%
    \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

And insert the title with:

```
\mytitle{
\flushright
\textsf{\LARGE Monetary Policy Normalization in the United States}
\vskip36pt
\textit{Stephen Williamson}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd be inclined to use `tcolorbox` and hook it into the `\@maketitle` declaration.  In the `article` class, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Just for this example
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% Define some colour for the background
\definecolor{titlecol}{cmyk}{0.30,0.15,0.00,0.10}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% fake text for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Set up some lengths
\newlength\titleoffset
\setlength\titleoffset{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2 + 1in\relax}
\newlength\titlestretch
\setlength\titlestretch{\dimexpr \textwidth + \titleoffset \relax}

% The tcolorbox macro for use in `\@maketitle`
\newtcolorbox{titlebox}{
  % colours
  colback=titlecol, colframe=titlecol,
  % general
  sharp corners, width=\titlestretch, enlarge left by=-\titleoffset,
  height=3cm,
  % upper box
  fontupper=\Large\sffamily\bfseries, flushright upper,
  % lower box
  fontlower=\itshape, flushright lower, valign lower=bottom
}

% the \@maketitle macro
\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \begin{titlebox}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
\@title
\tcblower
\@author
    \vskip 1em%
\@date
  \end{titlebox}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

% Your standard "metadata"
\title{Monetary Policy Normalization in the United States}
\author{Stephen D. Williamson%
  \thanks{Thanks to Thomas F. Sturm for
    \texttt{tcolorbox}!}}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Compare this
\noindent
\begin{titlebox}

Monetary Policy Normalization in the United States

\tcblower

Stephen D. Williamson
\end{titlebox}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Don't forget you can pack all the relevant stuff into your own `.sty` file and load it with the standard `\usepackage{<filename>}`. In this case, you can dispense with the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. The solution by Jon is very elegant and I am certainly learning from it. I did not know the mdframed pkg. Thanks fro the pointer.